# Lining up label outputs in C# arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have this code so far, and am having issues with lining up the information output correctly. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong at the moment. Maybe it would be better off with one label

It is supposed to look like

```
Price    .10      .15      .20      .25
--------------------------------------
10.00    1.00    1.50     2.00     2.25
15.00    1.50    2.25     3.00     3.25
20.00    2.00    3.00     4.00     5.00
25.00    2.50    3.75     5.00     6.25
```

But it looks like

```
Price       .10      .15      .20      .25
-----------------------------------------------
10.00       2.00    3.00     4.00     5.00       3.00     4.50     6.00    etc. etc.

20.00

30.00

40.00

50.00
```

I would greatly appreciate any help with this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TippingTable2GUI
{
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        double dinnerPrice = Convert.ToDouble(minPrice.Text);
        double tipRate;
        double tip;

        double maxRate = Convert.ToDouble(maxTax.Text);
        double lowRate = Convert.ToDouble(minTax.Text);
        double minDinner = Convert.ToDouble(minPrice.Text);
        double maxDinner = Convert.ToDouble(maxPrice.Text);

        const double TIPSTEP = 0.05;

        const double DINNERSTEP = 10.00;


        tipRate = lowRate;


        label1.Text = "";
        label6.Text = "";
        label7.Text = "";
        label9.Text = "Price";
        for (tipRate = lowRate; tipRate <= maxRate; tipRate += TIPSTEP)

        label1.Text = label1.Text + String.Format("{0, 10}", tipRate.ToString("C"));


label8.Text="--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------";


  while (dinnerPrice <= maxDinner)

          {
  label6.Text = label6.Text + String.Format("{0, -10}\n\n", dinnerPrice.ToString("C"));



  while (tipRate <= maxRate)
           {
   tip = dinnerPrice * tipRate;
   label7.Text = label7.Text + String.Format("{0, 10}", tip.ToString("C"));

   tipRate += 0.05;
                    } 


                    dinnerPrice += DINNERSTEP;
                    tipRate = lowRate;



            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please include some more code with where the arrays that the numbers are coming from, and how you're loading them into your table. I'm guessing by the event handler that this is WinForms?

Comment: This is basically a GUI application in visual studio. The initial numbers are coming from 4 text boxes. minTax maxTax minPrice max Price. The code puts the inbetween numbers for the table in steps of 0.05 for tips and the actual dinner costs steps up by 10.00. The actual output looks like the second code block and I am trying to get it to look like the first

Answer (score 0):

Read up on [string.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#FormatItem), i believe that would solve your problem.
The link goes directly to something that looks like your problem. But as a solution...

Comment: That does look like what I'm trying to do and I think I see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void buttonCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

double dinnerPrice = Convert.ToDouble(minPrice.Text);
double tipRate;
double tip;

double maxRate = Convert.ToDouble(maxTax.Text);
double lowRate = Convert.ToDouble(minTax.Text);
double minDinner = Convert.ToDouble(minPrice.Text);
double maxDinner = Convert.ToDouble(maxPrice.Text);

const double TIPSTEP = 0.05;

const double DINNERSTEP = 10.00;


tipRate = lowRate;


label1.Text = "";
label6.Text = "";
label7.Text = "";

for (tipRate = lowRate; tipRate <= maxRate; tipRate += TIPSTEP)
    label1.Text = label1.Text + String.Format(" {0, 8}", tipRate.ToString("F"))+"\t";\\Use Tab here for proper spacing
label1.Text = label1.Text + String.Format("{0, 8}", tipRate.ToString("C"))+"\t";//Use Tab here for proper spacing
const int NUM_DASHES = 50;
for (int x = 0; x < NUM_DASHES; ++x) ;//Instead of this loop use static dashes like this.
```

lable2.Text=""---------------------------;

```
while (dinnerPrice <= maxDinner)
{
    label6.Text = label6.Text + String.Format("{0, 8}", dinnerPrice.ToString("C"))+"\t";//Use Tab here for proper spacing
    while (tipRate <= maxRate)
    {
        tip = dinnerPrice * tipRate;
        label7.Text = label7.Text + String.Format("{0, 8}", tip.ToString("F"))+"\t";//Use Tab here for proper spacing
        tipRate += 0.05;
    } 
    dinnerPrice += DINNERSTEP;
    tipRate = lowRate;

}
```

}

Comment: I see what you're saying about spacing, I'm still working on the actual format to match the one I posted above

Comment: I've managed to get the prices lined up, tip amounts still screwed. Also the tip amounts for the lowest price, in this case 10.00 is missing for some reason

Comment: while loop discarding last value may be you need to use do-while loop to get last value or use forloop. i think you need to add some sort of line feed or line break at the end of each iteration.